# Session Timeout timer did not wait for audio track playing time

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html5-audio, session-state

I have lot of checkbox is available in my website when user select any checkbox the corresponding audio track will be playing.

In this page we use session timeout for 2 mins inactivity but issue is some time audio track is playing more than 2 mins in this time our session timer take audio playing time also so our session ended before audio track completed.

How to make session timeout timer starts after current audio track completed.

Audio element is not available in DOM  the audio track is available in JS file.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear interval on audio starts and check if audio ends with [ended](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_ended.asp) property or [onEnded event](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp) then start session timeout again.

```
var player = document.getElementById('player');
player.addEventListener('play', function() {
  // Stop session timer
});
player.addEventListener('ended', function() {
  // Start session timer again
});
```

Comment: The issue is video tag is available in my js in this the ended property will work?

Comment: How to get the current playing audio details it is not available in my don

Comment: @CodeMan elements don't have to be in the DOM for events to trigger.